# Nbextension not displaying full list

Tags: jupyter-notebook, configurable, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am setting up the nbextensions on a new desktop. My previous one on the old desktop (pic1) has a lot more extensions then this new one (pic2). Tried to search from the filter, won't display either.

Anyone have a clue of what's going on here?

I used `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` in anaconda prompt since our company firewall prevents me from using pip install

Previous:
[image]

New:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue, and this line solved my problem:

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```